# How to club together words in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a scalar value as

**Eighty Thousand and Seven Thousand and Nine Hundred and Eighty Nine**

How can I make it **Eighty Seven Thousand Nine Hundred Eighty Nine**

So far I have been able to find the position of occurrence but after that I am lost

```
with cte as
(select 'Eighty Thousand and Seven Thousand and Nine Hundred and Eighty Nine' as name
), 
pos as
(select patindex('%Thousand%',name) pos, name from cte
union all
select pos+patindex('%Thousand%',substring(name, pos+1, len(name))) pos, name from pos
where patindex('%Thousand%',substring(name, pos+1, len(name)))>0
)
select pos from pos
```

Comment: A guess: split on "and" and convert each part to numbers (eighty thousand = 80000), then add all and convert the result back to text. Although this will fail on "seven hundred and eighty thousand" - 780000)

Comment: You might do better parsing the string into an integer value and then converting the integer to your favorite prose style. Your single example can be broken apart at the "and"s and each fragment converted and summed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
Declare @String1 varchar(100) Declare @String2 varchar(100) declare @string nvarchar(264)
set @string = N'Eighty Thousand and Seven Thousand and Nine Hundred and Eighty Nine';
-- Ensure it ends with a space
SET @string = @string + ' ';
WITH cte (Id, Value, Rest)
AS (SELECT 1 as Id,SUBSTRING(@string, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', @string, 1) - 1) AS Value ,SUBSTRING(@string, CHARINDEX(' ', @string, 1) + 1, LEN(@string)) AS Value
    UNION ALL SELECT Id + 1 AS Id,SUBSTRING(Rest, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', Rest, 1) - 1) AS Value,SUBSTRING(Rest, CHARINDEX(' ', Rest, 1) + 1, LEN(Rest)) AS Value  FROM cte WHERE  CHARINDEX(' ', Rest, 1) <> 0)

SELECT @String1= Value
FROM cte
WHERE id = 2; -- = 2rd word to get
WITH cte1 (Id, Value, Rest)
AS (SELECT 1 as Id,SUBSTRING(@string, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', @string, 1) - 1) AS Value ,SUBSTRING(@string, CHARINDEX(' ', @string, 1) + 1, LEN(@string)) AS Value
    UNION ALL SELECT Id + 1 AS Id,SUBSTRING(Rest, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', Rest, 1) - 1) AS Value,SUBSTRING(Rest, CHARINDEX(' ', Rest, 1) + 1, LEN(Rest)) AS Value FROM cte1 WHERE  CHARINDEX(' ', Rest, 1) <> 0)
SELECT @String2 =Value
FROM cte1
WHERE id = 5; -- = 5rd word to get
IF @String1=@String2
Begin set @string = Replace(Replace(@string,'Thousand and',''),'  ',' ') Print @string
END
```